# How to send and receive broadcast message

Tags: android, broadcast, message-passing

I am trying to pass data between two activities that are inside of tabs.  I am trying to use `sendBroadcast()`.  With breakpoints set I never reach `onReceive()`.

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".WebResults"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.toxy.LOAD_URL" />
    </intent-filter>         
</activity>
```

Activity Sender:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WebResults.class);
intent.setAction("com.toxy.LOAD_URL");
intent.putExtra("url",uri.toString());
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Activity Receiver :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.toxy.LOAD_URL");
    this.registerReceiver(new Receiver(), filter);
}

private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        String url = arg1.getExtras().getString("url");
        WebView webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put everything in one activity, rather than using separate activities for the tabs, and you will no longer need to try to use broadcasts to communicate between them.

Comment: How i can unregister this receiver?

Comment: you should change the question title, it is not helping people who searched "How to send and receive broadcast message" and got here by google first result, the people who answered you all suggested another approach other than sending broadcast

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you, but I figured out:

Remove the intent filter from the manifest and change

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WebResults.class);
```

for

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

Please use

```
intent.getStringExtra("");
```

and

```
new Intent();
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("msg");    //action: "msg"
intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("message", message.getBody());
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then for receiving write something like this (inside Activity)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
           /* Toast.makeText(context, "Message is: "+ intent.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();*/
            String action = intent.getAction();
            switch (action){
                case "msg":
                    String mess = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                    txt.setText(mess);
                    break;
            }
        }

    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("msg");
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sender Activity:**

Hello,From your sender's Activity you just need to specify the action and extra data for the implicite broadcast intent that will be launched based on some condition.

Example of an implicite broadcast  ;

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setAction("com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION");

intent.putExtra("data_key", "hello all");

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

You can also use adb:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION --es data_key "hello all"
```

**Receiver Avtivity**:

Now on the receiver's Activity you can normally register your broadcast under your onCreate() or onResume() .

You will then unregister under onPause() or onDestroy() callback or if you destroy your activity, that's why your listening scope is limited to the receiver activity lifetime.

*Note:* from API26+ , only activities currently running(background or foreground) will detect this type of broadcast
You cannot declare them on the Manifest.xml of your application if you target android 8.0(Api26)