# Want to send data to another activity on getting data

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-activity

I have an activity in which i am getting some value in string and i want to send that data to another activity. The data that i want to send changes frequently after calling some method. So i want to send updated data into another activity. My data will be updated anytime no matter whether i am on that activity or not. My code

```
    if (event.equals("gameRequstinvitaion")) {
                        try {
                            socket.emit("gameRequstinvitaion", jsonObject);
                            gamerequest = jsonObject.toString();
                            Log.e("TAG", "gamereq" + gamerequest);
}
}
```

My gamerequest will be updated anytime so i want to send updated data to another activity. Is it possible?PleASE HELP ME OUT

Comment: No i already have activity started. I only want to send data to another activity that has already been started before....

Comment: Please clarify your requirement. Is there some service running that keeps on updating data?? Or it is just one activity?

Comment: Its just an activity.......some method will call so it will update new data ,.....

Comment: If you want to send data to the previous activity then you can use putExtra and the finishing current activity previous activity will receive updated data.

Comment: can it be possibel with sharedpreference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Handler to send data to another activity

```
  public static Handler handler;

handler=new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg1) {

        //-- retreiving data
        String data=msg.obj.toString();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now pass data from activity 1

```
 Message msg=new Message();
msg.obj="Test Message";//Pass any type of value
Activity2.handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Cheers

Comment: Please do check the answer so that no one faces such a problem again..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is sending and receiving broadcast messages between activities.
Refer:

[How to send and receive broadcast message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907713/how-to-send-and-receive-broadcast-message)

Or This tutorial.
http://hmkcode.com/android-sending-receiving-custom-broadcasts/

Comment: But how to get the data in async task on changing the data....

Comment: I think I misread your question, have updated my answer

Comment: What if i use Async task???

Comment: How to do in my both activities?

Comment: If you use AsyncTask, you will have to create the Activity2 inside the doInBackground method, by passing the context from Activity1 to it as arguments. I am not sure you would be able to do this, have never tried. If you can, well, you're welcome :)

Comment: How to do in my both activities? – Create two separate broadcast send/receive in the activities maybe

Comment: The given example extends broadcast receiver and i want to extend activity in both classes.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62107/discussion-between-arnab-and-mehdi).

Answer (score 0):

use of interface...

when the upload is successfull , it will fire the interface method

in that defination of method in activity will navigate to activity to carry data with put extra.

Comment: i am not getting it. Can you please explain it with some code.