# android how to send a system broadcast

Tags: android, testing, adb, broadcast

I am working with testing android app's power consumption
and to make the app consump most power as possible,I want to send a system broadcast like "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADD",but the system reboot when I send it by adb shell am broadcast command.

So is there any method to send a system broadcast?

Comment: what makes you think that your issue is caused by "improper" broadcast sending method?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can see here sulution:

[Some themes in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907713/how-to-send-and-receive-broadcast-message)

[One simple tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-sending-receiving-custom-broadcasts/)

more detail you can see in official documentation developer.andorid

Comment: thanks for your answers, but I want to send some system broadcast ,broadcasts like "android.intent.action.CALL" can be sent by adb shell command,but others like "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" cann't be sent by app,the device would reboot or exception "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"

Comment: Some broadcasts are protected. See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#130

Maybe you bradcasted android.intent.action.CALL on an Android < N? That would explain why that protected broadcast would work.